# How to delete part of a line that does not match a pattern?

Tags: regular-expression, substitute

I'd like to remove everything apart of my pattern match.

For example I've the following line:

```
window.page4_callback(["here \"is\" some text"]);
```

and I'd like to leave the text only within the double quotes, so the expected output is:

```
here \"is\" some text
```

Matching pattern is `/".*"` and its removal can be performed by using substitute:

```
:s/".*"//g
```

however how do you do opposite?

I've tried to use vglobal (`:v/pattern/d`), but it would normally remove the whole line, but in my case it's saying:

> Pattern found in every line: `".*"`

I've found similar issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6249172/55075), but I'm even more confused.

Comment: Similar: [Remove everything except regex match in Vim](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4503748/55075) at SO

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are probably a bunch of ways to do this; here's my attempt:

```
:%s/.*"\(.\{-}\)".*/\1/
```

The key part is `"\(.\{-}\)"`; this non-greedily matches everything in between quotes. This will match:

> window.page4_callback([`"here is some text"`]);

The parentheses are there to start a subgroup, so we can reference it with `\1` on the replacing side. We surround this with `.*` on both ends to match the rest of the line.

So this doesn't really "delete a non-matching pattern", as the title says. Rather, it deletes the *entire line*, and replaces it with a specific subgroup we matched earlier. The effect is the same, and for me, this is an easier way to think about it.

Conclusion: capturing subgroups is good. Subgroups are your friends.

---

**Edit**

To also work after your edited post :-)

```
:%s/^.\{-}"\(.*\)".\{-}$/\1/
```

This is a variant of the above, but notice we use `.\{-}` before and after the   `"` now, to match as little as possible; plus, we anchor it to the start and end of the line with `^` and `$`.

You can then replace the `\"` with a second `:substitute` command:

```
:%s/\\"/"/
```

This still won't work with something like:

```
window.function("arg1", "arg2");
```

This will leave you with:

```
arg1", "arg2
```

But I'm not sure if that's a requirement :-)

Comment: You don't need `.\{-}` here, `.*` would match the same thing. In both cases the last fragment that's surrounded by double quotes is retained.

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way is to use `grep --only-matching`.

```
:%!grep --only-matching --extended-regexp '".*"'
```

However if you want a completely Vim solution then you can use `:s` with an expression replacement:

```
:let @a=""
:%s//\=setreg('A', submatch(0), 'l')/g
:%d _
:pu a
:0d _
```

Or all on a single line:

```
:let @a=""|%s/".*"/\=setreg('A', submatch(0), 'l')/g|%d _|pu a|0d _
```

In brief, this uses a substitution to append each match into register "a" linewise then replace the entire buffer with the contents of register "a"

See my answer at "[Remove everything except regex match in Vim](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4521486/660921)" for a fuller explanation.

Concerns:

- This will trash one of your registers. This example trashed `@a`
- Uses the last search pattern. Although you can modify the substitute command with whatever pattern you want: `%s/<pattern>/\=setreg('A', submatch(0), 'l')/g`

Comment: Thanks, I actually used `grep -o '".*"'` for sake of simplicity.

Answer (score 3):

```
yi[       " yank what's between the brackets
S         " delete line and start insert
<C-r>0    " insert last yanked text
```

Answer (score 2):

You could build up a list of the matches, delete everything, and then paste the match list:

```
let old_c = @c

let @c=""
exec a:firstline .','. a:lastline .'sub//\=setreg("C", submatch(0), "l")/g'
exec a:firstline .','. a:lastline .'delete _'
put! c

let @c = old_c
```

[vim-searchsavvy](https://github.com/idbrii/vim-searchsavvy) provides a `:ClearAllButMatches` command that [uses the above code](https://github.com/idbrii/vim-searchsavvy/blob/master/autoload/searchsavvy.vim#L28-L49). You do your search, call the command, and only text that matched the command remain. Multiple matches on one line will be put on separate lines.